# Python dictionary sort by key and by value

Tags: python

**Task:
Frequency analyzer. Read a text from a txt file. Output words that met in the text one word by one line. Words must be sorted by descending and if some words have equal frequency they should be sorted by lexicographical order.**

In my implementation after text parsing we have a dictionary of pairs such as ('word',frequency), for example ('hello',20). So the problem is how to write a predicate in order to get desired result. Here is my logic:
pseudo code
sort by  frequency desc until get equal frequency,
when equal frequency met sort by lexicographical order of word.
My code seems like that, but the testing machine output "The time limit exceed", probably because of sorting twice.

```
wordlist = []
    with open('words.txt','r') as f:
wordlist = [word for line in f for word in line.split()]
words = dict(zip(wordlist,[wordlist.count(p) for p in wordlist]))
dic = []
for key,val in words.items():
    dic.append((key,val))
dic.sort(key=lambda a: (a[0]), reverse=False)
dic.sort(key=lambda a: (a[1]), reverse=True)
for word in dic:
    print(word[0])
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in the post. It is not clear which lines are supposed to belong together.

Comment: `words = collections.Counter(wordlist)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the second element of the tuple is a number, you can invert the direction of the sort by inverting the number itself, which means you only need to sort once by using an appropriate key.

```
dic.sort(key=lambda a: (-a[1], a[0]))
```

It is slightly simpler, though, to use `sorted` directly on the return value of `words.items()`:

```
dic = sorted(words.items(), key=lambda a: (-a[1], a[0]))
```

---

If you couldn't use the negative-number trick, you'd have to write an explicit comparison function and convert it to a key using the `functools` module.

```
def tup_compare(t1, t2):
    w1, c1 = t1
    w2, c2 = t2
    if w1 < w2:
        return 1
    elif w1 > w2:
        return -1
    elif c1 < c2:
        return -1
    elif c1 == c2:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
dic = sorted(words.items, key=functools.cmp_to_key(tup_compare))
```

Comment: Should be `-a[1], a[0]`? (frequency before lexicographic)

Comment: Looks like it; I didn't really look at the intended order.

Comment: I'd write: `lambda word, count: (-count, word)`.